# How can i find, match and replace end of line when there is a match

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

This question might easy, I am new to natural language processing. I have million lines like the example below. I want to replace the last match in a line with another.

**My problem is like this**

```
user,user,'  i got the sims 3'  
user,user,   
user,user,'  cheer up liz'   
user,user,'  you ok mate? do you have skype btw?'  
user,user,  
user,user,'  i just played give it away in response to your tweet'
```

*The expected output*

```
user,user,'  i got the sims 3'  
user,user, 'hi'  
user,user,' cheer up liz'   
user,user,' you ok mate? do you have skype btw?'  
user,user, 'hi'  
user,user, 'hi'    
user,user,'  i just played give it away in response to your tweet'
```

I have tried *sed* replace at end of the line with the following codes that has not worked

```
sed 's/,$/,""/g' filename > filename 2
sed 's/user,user,$/user,user,""/g' filename > filename 2

sed 's/,$/,''/g' filename > filename 2
sed 's/user,user,$/user,user,''/g' filename > filename 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk -v sq="'" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $3 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/{ $3 = " " sq "hi" sq } 1' file
user,user,'  i got the sims 3'
user,user, 'hi'
user,user,'  cheer up liz'
user,user,'  you ok mate? do you have skype btw?'
user,user, 'hi'
user,user,'  i just played give it away in response to your tweet'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your sed code inside double quotes.

```
sed "s/,[[:blank:]]*$/, 'hi'/" file
```

Comment: I see no reason and it works relatively to given sample with very simple and efficient code, just maybe a escaped `$` due to double quote (but work without on my system)